# Changing input name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have some hidden inputs like this

```
<input name="exam.normals[1].blahblah" ..../>
```

I would like somehow to replace the `[1]` with a number that I want (`index`).

I aint lazy but I am trying to find a good way to do this...

A solution would be a replace of `exam.normals[1]` with `exam.normals[+ index +]` but I should `substr` the whole string first....
With regexp I don’t know how to do the replace. good...

Comment: @Justin Johnson, you edited the question but left in "I aint lazy"? Hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$("input[name]").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr("name", $this.attr("name").match(/\[\d+]/g, "["+index+"]"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$("input[name*='[1]']").attr('name', function(i, v) {
  return v.replace('[1]', '[' + i + ']');
});
```

This finds inputs that have a name with `[1]` in them, then replaces `[1]` with `[0]` on the first `[1]` on the second, etc.